# iterate over an array of string adresses

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

hey im trying to iterate throughout the entire array of adresses to strings here is what i got so far :

```
int main()
{

  char arr1[]="hello";
  char arr2[]="ok";
  char arr3[]="goodbye";
  char arr4[] ="memo";
 
  char *sumOfAdresses[]={arr1,arr2,arr3,arr4};

  for(char**r=sumOfAdresses;*r!='\0';r++){
    printf("fadixa");
    printf("\n");
  }

  
  }
```

in this case im trying to print 4 times "fadixa" but this method doesnt seem to work, i cant put the size of the array as part of the assignment, this is only half part  of my homework and its only a test in main(this should be a method that accepts only **char and no size)

Comment: "im trying to print 4 times "fadixa" but this method doesnt seem to work, " --> The test `*r!='\0'` is exercised 5 times.  What do you think `r` is on the 5th time?

Comment: NickZzie, Can the `char *sumOfAdresses[]={arr1,arr2,arr3,arr4};` be re-defined to have an ending _null pointer_ : `char *sumOfAdresses[]={arr1,arr2,arr3,arr4, NULL};`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sizeof` operator to get the number of items in the `sumOfAdresses` array. You can also print the elements using the number of elements in the array.

###### Method 1

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char arr1[] = "hello", arr2[] = "ok", arr3[] = "goodbye", arr4[] = "memo";
    char *sumOfAdresses[] = { arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4 };
    
    for(char **pointer = sumOfAdresses; **pointer != '\0' ; pointer++)
        printf("%s\n", *pointer);

    return 0;
}
```

##### Method 2

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char arr1[] = "hello", arr2[] = "ok", arr3[] = "goodbye", arr4[] = "memo";
    char *sumOfAdresses[] = { arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4 };
    size_t i = 0; 
    
    for(char *pointer = *sumOfAdresses; *pointer != '\0' ; pointer++)
        printf("%s\n", sumOfAdresses[i++]);
      
    return 0;
}
```

###### Method 3

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char arr1[] = "hello", arr2[] = "ok", arr3[] = "goodbye", arr4[] = "memo";
    char *sumOfAdresses[] = { arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4 };
    size_t size = sizeof(sumOfAdresses) / sizeof(sumOfAdresses[0]);
      
    for(size_t i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", sumOfAdresses[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

This program produces the following output:

```
hello
ok
goodbye
memo
```

Comment: and lets say i build a method and into that method i pass a pointer that points to sumOFAdresses, how can i determine from that where my arrays (sumOfAdresses) finishes?

Comment: @NickZzie I guess method-1 meets what you want to say.

Comment: Methods 1 & 2: UB.  Perhaps `char *sumOfAdresses[] = { arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, "" };`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I tested locally but all methods are working. Where is the error?

Comment: thank you for this but maybe i was unclear about what i was asking
i have a function void AdressSwitcher(char **ch)
to this method i pass sumOfAdresses the question is how i define the size in the method itself

Comment: Methods 1& 2 attempts an array access outside `sumOfAdresses[]` - that is UB.  Where do you think `pointer` is when `*pointer != '\0'` supposedly occurs?

Comment: @NickZzie You do not.  "i pass sumOfAdresses" is a misunderstanding.  When an array is passed, it becomes the address of the first element of the array.  The info about array size if lost.  Use Method 3 and pass the size also.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'm using GCC but got any warnings. I suspected like you, but thought that since the `sumOfAdresses` pointer is initialized as an array, it would be guaranteed by the compiler that the last element would be `'\0'`.

Comment: @Sercan No it is not.  The last element is `arr4`.  I suspect you are thinking of _strings_.  `sumOfAdresses` is an array of pointers.

Comment: so there is no way for me to get the size of "sumOfAdresses" in the method that receives this adress?

Comment: @NickZzie Sure, pass the size and the address: `foo(size, sumOfAdresses);`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Additionally, since the owner of the post wants to print the data without using the size of the array, I tried not to use size in the first and second method; yes, this option can be a gamble. :)

Comment: maybe i made everything more complicated than it actually is because i misunderstood the question, basically all i need to do is create a method that receives multiple addresses of char arrays (strings) all i need to do is make sure the address of the shortest word is located at the first spot of the array of addresses and the longest string address is located at the last place in the array of addresses

Comment: @NickZzie Best to append such important info to your post than in distant comments.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i wanted to break down the code to small missions since i wanted to think about the idea myself, thats why i needed the size of the array of addresses to compare lenghts of arrays and determine which is the shortest.
any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: @NickZzie Be fair, I have 2 [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70616406/iterate-over-an-array-of-string-adresses/70616496?noredirect=1#comment124833389_70616406) to you and no answer yet.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica hey, which questions exactly? cant seem to find any post of yours asking me a question..

Answer (score 0):

```
*r
```

is type of char *  not char, you can not compare it with char '\0'

Comment: Well yes code can as comparing any pointer to some integer type and  value of 0 is as comparing to a _null pointer_, well defined in C.

Answer (score 0):

> method that accepts only `**char`

The common solution is to have the last element of the array as a *sentinel*, some known value not used elsewhere - like a *null pointer* to signify the end.

```
void method(char **r) {
  while (*r) {
    printf("<%s>", *r);
    r++;
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Call with

```
// char *sumOfAdresses[]={arr1,arr2,arr3,arr4};
char *sumOfAdresses[] = {arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, NULL};

method(sumOfAdresses);
```